# laravel javascript compare 2 boxes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have two different select boxes with the same data in Laravel and I was wondering how you could compare those 2 so that you can't select the same option in both selects.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('option_list', 'Choice 1', ['class' => 'col-sm-1 control-label']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        {!! Form::select('option_list1', $option1, null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('option_list', 'Choice 2', ['class' => 'col-sm-1 control-label']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        {!! Form::select('option_list2', $option2, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        {!! Form::submit('Submit!', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I was thinking about getting the id's from the 2 select boxes and then with an if statement checking of the two choices don't have the same id.

**UPDATE**

Do you maybe know how I can combine your Javascript code with the Select2 Javascript code.

Because with the Select2 code I can create a new field if it didn't exists. But than he cancels your Javascript code what I don not want to happen because it works perfecty!

```
        $('.option_list').select2({
        placeholder: "Select or add tags",
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        createTag: function(newTag) {
            return {
                id: newTag.term,
                text: newTag.term + ' (new)'
            };
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        // Get select elements
        var sel1 = document.getElementsByName('option_list1')[0];
        var sel2 = document.getElementsByName('option_list2')[0];

        // Cache each select options
        var opts1 = sel1.getElementsByTagName("option");
        var opts2 = sel2.getElementsByTagName("option");

        // Helper function for hiding an option in a select
        var hideOption = function (opts, val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
                if (opts[i].value == val) {
                    opts[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    opts[i].style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
        }

        // When selecting a value in the first select hide it in the second
        sel1.onchange = function () {
            hideOption(opts2, this.value);
        }

        // When selecting a value in the second select hide it in the first
        sel2.onchange = function () {
            hideOption(opts1, this.value);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dec5tdgx/5/).

---

There's also the jQuery approach, if you want less code:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        // Get select elements
        var sel1 = $('[name=option_list1]');
        var sel2 = $('[name=option_list2]');

        // Cache each select options
        var opts1 = sel1.children('option');
        var opts2 = sel2.children('option');

        // When selecting a value in the first select hide it in the second
        sel1.change(function () {
            opts2.show().filter('[value=' + this.value + ']').hide();
        });

        // When selecting a value in the second select hide it in the first
        sel2.change(function () {
            opts1.show().filter('[value=' + this.value + ']').hide();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

And here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xs7pt228/3/) for this one.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but your code says that if select box 1 is not the same as select box 2, then maken select box 2 the same as one? I want the opposite of it, if in select box 1, option 1 is chosen. Then you cannot select option 1 in select box 2.

Comment: My mistake, I read _can_ instead of _can't_ and somehow misunderstood the question :). I've updated the answer with a correct solution.

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can combine your Javascript code with the Select2 Javascript code?

Comment: Unfortunately `select2` is really lacking on that subject. But you can trick it by disabling the options and then having a CSS rule that hides the disabled options form the select2 option list. Here you can check out a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xs7pt228/6/).

Comment: Thank you @Bogdan again! I have used your code, modified a little bit at the top and it still worked. I can now use the `select2`, no multiple selects and make a new one if I want. [Here is the end code](http://jsfiddle.net/xs7pt228/7/)